# How to make discord bot DM a user when it's offline on Replit

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm hosting a python discord bot on Replit.com 24/7 with a hacker plan.

Is there a way to make the bot DM me when the code stops running by any reason?

I've tried the `atexit` and `signal` function but it's not doing anything when I stop the code. Here's the code:

```
import atexit
import signal

async def handle_exit():
  user = await getUserByID(my_ID)
  await user.send(f"{bot.user} is offline! :x:")

atexit.register(handle_exit)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handle_exit)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_exit)

#discord code here
```

Any other way than DM on discord is okay too, as long as I get notified when the bot goes offline.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: if u repl never goes offline? then? i have a trick to make it online

Comment: About a few weeks ago, it was going offline by itself for unknown reason so I'm asking just in case it happens again.

Comment: so how are u making ur bot up using hacker plan or uptimerobot?

Comment: I'm using the hacker plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, so u have to add an file with flask server :

```py
from threading import Thread
from itertools import cycle
from flask import Flask

app = Flask('')

@app.route('/test')
def main():
  return "Your Bot Is Ready"

@app.route('/')
def lol():
  return "Your Bot Is Ready"

def run():
  app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)

def keep_alive():
  server = Thread(target=run)
  server.start()
```

and then import that file in ur main.py or bot file and then add `file_name.keep_alive()`

and then make a new bot and use following code:

```py
from discord.ext import commands
import requests

bot = commands.Bot(prefix="!")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  channel = bot.get_channel()
  while True:
    r = requests.get("url that u get on bar of replit")
    if r.status_code != 200:
      await channel.send("bot is offline")
    

bot.run("token of another bot")
```

and to get url [image]